# How do I use pictures as custom icons in Leaflet?

Tags: r, r-leaflet

I am trying to create an interactive map of football stadiums in the UK with the leaflet package in R. I understand that I can use a custom image as the icon on the map. For a given stadium, I would like to use the badge of the club that plays there as the icon. Initially I am trying to solve the simpler problem of just using one custom image for all the stadiums with the hope that once I can solve this, I will be able to generalise and have one custom image per stadium. I will provide a simplified data set of just two stadiums for the purposes of this question.

So far I have tried using this picture (https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e5/AFC_Bournemouth_%282013%29.svg) of the Bournemouth badge however it does not appear on the map when run. I think R cannot properly access this image but I am not sure what types it can access or how it accesses them.

So far my code looks like this

```r
library(leaflet)

# Create Data
finalData <-  data.frame(Club = c("A.F.C. Bournemouth", "A.F.C. Wimbledon"), Latitude = c("50.7352","51.4051"), Longitude = c("-1.83839","-0.281984"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Create map using leaflet
m <- leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles()

# Attempt to create custom icon using the linked picture
BournemouthIcon = makeIcon("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e5/AFC_Bournemouth_%282013%29.svg", iconWidth = 8, iconHeight = 8)

m %>% addMarkers(lat = as.numeric(finalData$Latitude), 
                 lng = as.numeric(finalData$Longitude), 
                 clusterOptions = markerClusterOptions(), 
                 icon = BournemouthIcon)
```

I expect to see the 2 stadiums plotted on the map with the Bournemouth badge as the marker but instead the markers are blank.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiO6T.png) It appears R knows where to plot the points (since if you zoom out it detects the cluster of points), however it does not know what to mark the point with.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIG1I.png) This links back to my misunderstanding of how R is reading the picture I supplied. Any help with how to properly build a custom marker and then pass it to addMarkers would be greatly appreciated. Furthermore some guidance on generalising this to having a unique custom picture for each marker would also be great!

Comment: Your code works on my laptop. Try `iconWidth = 40, iconHeight = 40` to make sure the icon is in proper size.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yeah the code runs however for me the icon is just a small blue square with a question mark in, are you getting the correct icon? I. E. The linked picture